# how to create array of SubDocuments in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6178b6a61d8341796714e1c7"},
"name":"devi",
"**last":"zack",
"book":[{"book":"jungle book","pages":{"$numberInt":"33"},"_id":{"$oid":"6178ca6a52f39598**8a490241"}}

],"__v":{"$numberInt":"7"}}
```

Comment: please elaborate on your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please Describe More @Ukena So that we can understand and give you our best.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775976/update-subdocument-array-mongoose

Comment: sorry my question is in this link           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775976/update-subdocument-array-mongoose